# Systemd service running bash script fails

Tags: systemd, systemctl

On Arch Linux, I am trying to create a systemd service which runs this Bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

/bin/xbindkeys &
/bin/setxkbmap -layout gb
```

With some online guidance I then made a file named `myfirst.service` in `/etc/systemd/system` to store my service. Here are the contents of the file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Command Service

[Service]
ExecStart=/etc/startupjobscript
User=user1
Type=oneshot
Restart=on-abort
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The service is supposed to execute `/etc/startupjobscript`, which is the Bash script. After this I enabled and started the service with:

```
systemctl enable myfirst
systemctl start myfirst
```

But for some reason it doesn't work and shows that it has failed to load and run at all.

EDIT: here is what **sudo systemctl status myfirst** give me:

```
Warning: The unit file, source configuration file or drop-ins of myfirst.service changed on disk. Run 'systemctl daemon-reload' to reload units.
● myfirst.service - Command Service
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/myfirst.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2020-08-26 21:07:02 BST; 18min ago
    Process: 332 ExecStart=/etc/startupjobscript (code=exited, status=255/EXCEPTION)
   Main PID: 332 (code=exited, status=255/EXCEPTION)

Aug 26 21:07:01 archlinux systemd[1]: Starting Command Service...
Aug 26 21:07:02 archlinux startupjobscript[337]: Cannot open display "default display"
Aug 26 21:07:02 archlinux systemd[1]: myfirst.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=255/EXCEPTION
Aug 26 21:07:02 archlinux systemd[1]: myfirst.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 26 21:07:02 archlinux systemd[1]: Failed to start Command Service.
```

Comment: Did you run `systemctl daemon-reload`?

Comment: I see you've put your script in `/etc/`. Normally, things in `/etc` are configuration files with permission 644.  Check if your script has execute permissions (755)  -- plus I recommend sticking it in `/usr/local/bin` or `/usr/local/sbin`.  If it's not execute permissions, what is the output of `systemctl status myfirst`?

Comment: Since your service works with X, it might be useful to use `WantedBy=graphical.target` instead of `multi-user.target` to ensure the X server is started before you try interfacing with it.  I don't think this is the problem, but `systemctl status` output should tell us.

Comment: I see multiple issues: 1) X utilities need a `DISPLAY` to act upon; it's a variable set in the environment of the user(s) who are running an X instance, it's not available to a _system_ systemd unit. 2) X utilities will likely fail until the graphical environment is up and running for the user that runs them, which will most likely only happen at a later moment than `multi-user.target` or `graphical.target` or the user's `default.target`. You may want to detail what you're trying to achieve, users here may suggest better approaches.

Comment: @Panki Yes i have and it hasnt fixed anything

Comment: @Stewart I have just switched the file to /usr/local/bin and yes it has execute permissions 777, I have edited my question with the output of **systemctl status myfirst**, Also what section should i add **WantedBy=graphical.target** such as [Unit], [Service] or [Install]

Comment: When you see `Warning: The unit file, source configuration file or drop-ins ...` it means you should run `systemctl daemon-reload` and then try again.  No need to `systemctl enable` yet until you need to get it working on boot.

Comment: @Stewart I have ran that command but nothing has happend or anything so im not sure what to do anymore :/

Comment: I'm writing some info as an answer.

Comment: @fra-san ok so how would i add a DISPLAY in my .service file im using xcfe and im not quite sure what to write.

Answer (score 2):

When running anything that talks to the X-server, systemd services get a little tricky.  There are two main methods to do it:

1. Run a user service
2. Set `$DISPLAY` and avoid starting until `graphical.target` is reached.

To run this as a user-service, move `myfirst.service` to `~/.config/systemd/system/`.  Then remove `User=` and set `WantedBy=` to `default.target`.  `default.target` is reached when the user logs in.  Some day there will be a `graphical-session.target` which will be reached when a user is logged into a desktop environment, but that's not available yet.  Instead we are triggering off of `default.target` which is reached when a user logs in.  If you're using a display manager, then you probably have an x-session before then.

```
[Unit]
Description=Command Service
After=default.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/xbindkeys
ExecStartPost=/bin/setxkbmap -layout gb
Type=simple
Restart=on-abort

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Be sure to use `--user` when working with this unit such as:

```
systemctl --user daemon-reload
systemctl --user start myfirst.service
systemctl --user enable myfirst.service
```

---

To keep this as a system service, leave the file in `/etc/systemd/system/` and  you'll need to set environment so it can connect to the X-server.  Finally, be sure to make it `WantedBy=graphical.target`. This ensures it doesn't try to connect to the X-server before the X-server is started.  However I'm not sure that it will always succeed because I'm not sure that the .Xauthority is valid until you log in.

```
[Unit]
Description=Command Service
After=graphical.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/xbindkeys
ExecStartPost=/bin/setxkbmap -layout gb
Type=simple
User=user1
Environment=DISPLAY=:0
Environment=XAUTHORITY=/home/user1/.Xauthority
Restart=on-abort

[Install]
WantedBy=graphical.target
```

The system-wide service thing gets a little weird if you have multiple users or multiple displays. It's recommended to do the user-specific thing.  If you are in your desktop environment, you can `echo $DISPLAY` and `echo $XAUTHORITY` to figure out what to set those variables to.

---

Once you make these changes, you'll need to tell `systemd` to read them before you try your next `start`.  Run:

```
systemctl daemon-reload
```

If you've been experimenting, be sure to `systemctl disable myfirst.service` first, then when you are sure `systemctl start myfirst.service` works, then you can `systemctl enable myfirst.service`.  `enable` will create a symbolic link in `default.target` or `graphical.target` so that when you reboot, your service gets called.  To avoid making a mess with those links during your experimentation state, just don't enable it until you're ready to test reboots.

---

Note, I do have a strange suspicion about that `/bin/xbindkeys &` line in your bash script.  Does `xbindkeys` normally run forever?  If so, you might want to change your `ExecStart=` to:

```
ExecStart=/bin/xbindkeys
ExecStartPost=/bin/setxkbmap -layout gb
Type=simple
```

I've made these changes to the suggested units above already.

This will ensure that systemd keeps track of the process directly instead of forking.  Because `Type=` is not set to `forking`, I suspect that the bash script will end and systemd won't keep track of the PID of `xbindkeys` leaving it as an orphaned PID and no way to stop it.  If you leave `xbindkeys` as part of the `ExecStart` then stopping the service will terminate xbindkeys (which I think it will fail to do right now).  In that case you'll also want to set `Type=simple` because `oneshot` won't be applicable anymore.

Comment: Hi i tried to move to the file to ~/.config/systemd/system/ which does not exist in my system keep in mind im using arch linux

Comment: @Qasim That directory is expected not to exist by default, it is safe to just create it.

Comment: I'm afraid both of these approaches are not going to work (tried on Arch with SDDM and Xorg). I guess there isn't yet any X server listening for commands from `user1` when `default.target` or `graphical.target` are reached.

Comment: What error are you getting? Can you update your question with your latest `*.service` and `systemctl status`? Also, do these commands work if you run them from your own bash environment?

Comment: @Stewart I'm gonna try this out and see if it works and get back to you

Comment: @Stewart I should have been more clear: of course, your services work when manually started, _if_ a graphical session exists for `user1`. But, as far as I can see, they can't work when `enable`d and started automatically by systemd at boot. Regardless of the exact errors (the system unit complains about being unable to open display `:0`, the user unit can't find `DISPLAY` in its environment), the point is that there is no X session yet for `user1` when systemd's `target`s are reached.

Comment: Things get a bit tricky here.  The user-style service is more robust here because it doesn't activate until after the user logs in.  If you use a display manager, then your X-session (represented by `graphical.target`) will be available before you log in.  Don't forget the `WantedBy=default.target` which is user-specific.  If you don't use a display manager (you run `startx` from the terminal), then `default.target` may start before your `graphical.target` and that's what `graphical-session.target` will fix in the near future.  Don't forget `--user` when using systemctl on user units.

Comment: One extra trick you could try is to use `After=default.target` to the `[Unit]` section of the user unit.